# Closest point of plane $\pi: ax + by + cz + d = 0$ to point $(x_0, y_0, z_0)$

Tags: geometry

This seems to be one of the problems with available solutions on Wikipedia. Let us define a place $ax + by + cz + d = 0$ and a point $P := (x_0, y_0, z_0)$ such that we seek for a point $(x, y, z) =: Q \in \pi$ which minimizes the Euclidean distance $d(P, Q) = \lvert\lvert P-Q\rvert\rvert_2 = \sqrt{(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2+(z-z_0)^2}$. Before we go into algebraic details, the statement is below subject to constraint $ax + by + cz + d = 0$.

$$\min\limits_{Q} \, d(P, Q)$$

The development is:

1. Describe constrained objective function $J$ as sum $d(P, Q) + \lambda (ax + by + cz + d)$;
2. Perform partial derivatives $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$, $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial \lambda}$;
3. Manipulate algebraically to find expressions $(f_0, f_1, f_2)$ for variables $(x, y, \lambda)$;

Could you help me know, if there is any closed formula in literature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem can be easily solved geometrically noting that the line connecting the point $(x_0,y_0,z_0) $ and the closest point of the plane is necessarily perpendicular to the plane, i.e. parallel to the vector $(a,b,c)$.

This means that there exists such $t\in\mathbb R$ that
$$
(x,y,z)=(x_0,y_0,z_0)-(a,b,c)t.\tag1
$$
Since additionally the point $(x,y,z)$ satisfies the plane equation one readily obtains:
$$
t=\frac {ax_0+by_0+cz_0+d}{a^2+b^2+c^2}.\tag2
$$